# how to build libav for Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, video-encoding, libavcodec, libav

I have custom an camera app in Windows Phone 8. I need add a watermark image to each frame from camera capture and then record to a video.

WP8 start supporting native now. And i customized frames, but i can't find any solution for encoding these frames (images) to a video. My app likes a video recorder from camera.

Now i am working for building libav library for video encoding. http://www.libav.org/. using Windows Phone Component project. But i still having many errors. Please help me.

Thanks,

Comment: With the advent of wp8.1 I think it supports Native H264 encoding